# Given function $ f : I \to \Bbb R$, if it is strictly increasing, bounded and continuous, then $I$ must be a bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, fake-proofs

Can someone help explain why this statement is false

Comment: You try adding (or re-adding) the context of the question and the reasons why you thought it was true. Your question will be better received this way.

Answer (score 2):

You use the fact that "strictly increasing continuous functions send sequences which diverge to infinity to sequences which diverge to infinity". This is false, and overall your claim is false. For instance, consider the function $$f(x)=\arctan x$$

Comment: You were 8 seconds faster than me!

Comment: would you be able to help explain why the statement is false?

Comment: I can and I already did by providing a counterexample.

Comment: very valid point sorry about that, I now understand why. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are trying to prove is not true. Consider, for example, the function $\arctan$.

Answer (score 0):

Or the poor man's $\arctan x:$ $f(x) = 1 - 1/x$ on $[1,\infty).$